# How to debug if Knitr quits unexpectedly when composing tikz figure

Tags: tikz-pgf, sweave, knitr

I have a `.Rnw` file that `Knitr` used to compile perfectly fine until my backend dataset changed. Probably then the size of the graph changed also. For reasons I don't understand `knitr` now stops abruptly compiling and `LaTex` kicks in compiling an uncompleted `.tex` produced by Knitr. I guess this is what happens since I see in my Activity Monitor (ESS buffer) the logs from `knitr` being replaced by the logs from `LaTex`. Following I paste the last part of the log, with the last few lines of the normal `knitr` process, which loaded an R script to produce a ggplot, being replace by `LaTex`...

```
  grid.arrange(gp2,gp1)

   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 
##------ Thu Oct 10 18:39:42 2013 ------##

\documentclass[nohyper]{tufte-handout}

\nonstopmode

\usepackage{tikz}

! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.26 \usepackage
                {tikz} 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 15456 strings out of 493311
 278701 string characters out of 6137850
 379859 words of memory out of 5000000
 18583 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 4403 words of font info for 15 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 957 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 56i,0n,92p,470b,151s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!


Quitting from lines 1-81 (my/path/time_series.R) 
Quitting from lines 84-NA (my/path/time_series.R) 
Error in getMetricsFromLatex(TeXMetrics) (from #91) : 
TeX was unable to calculate metrics for the following string
or character:

    Label

Common reasons for failure include:
  * The string contains a character which is special to LaTeX unless
    escaped properly, such as % or $.
  * The string makes use of LaTeX commands provided by a package and
    the tikzDevice was not told to load the package.

The contents of the LaTeX log of the aborted run have been printed above,
it may contain additional details as to why the metric calculation failed.
```

I can't figure out what the problem is since I don't see any clue in the `knitr` log. Clearly what stops the compilation of `.Rnw` is a `tikzDevice` figure produced with these lines:

```
\begin{figure*}
  \centering
<<child-time_series, child='figure/time_series.R',dev='tikz',fig.width=6,fig.height=3,out.width='.95\\textwidth',message=FALSE,echo=FALSE>>=
@

      \label{fig:TimeSeries}
\end{figure*}
```

I guess that the key is the following `LaTex` error (also above)

```
Error in getMetricsFromLatex(TeXMetrics) (from #91) : 
    TeX was unable to calculate metrics for the following string
    or character:

        Label
```

`Label` is the label of my plot.

Comment: Check if you have `preview` and `standalone` LaTeX packages installed. And, if I'm correct, you don't need wrapping into `figure`, `sweave/knitr` will done it themself.

Comment: @m0nhawk No luck. I checked and both `preview` and `standalone` are installed. I also tried to take the chunk out of `figure`but I get the very same error.

Comment: And what about `pgf` and `tikz`? Can you provide full document?

Comment: Installed. Both.

Comment: I'm curious how `child='figure/time_series.R'` worked before; the child document is supposed to be a `.Rnw` file instead of an R script.

Comment: Ops, didn't know that. Still before updating the dataset the `knitr` was correctly lunching the `R` script and the output plot was correctly embedded in the document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a chunk named `foo`, `knitr` first generates `figure/foo.tikz` using the `tikzDevice` package when the graphics device is `tikz`. Then `knitr` compiles this `.tikz` file to PDF via `pdflatex` (or other LaTeX engines depending on your setting). If there is anything wrong in this process, you can

- check the log file `figure/foo.log` for the error message
- open `figure/foo.tikz` (it is supposed to be a complete LaTeX document), and see if you can spot anything wrong
- try `cd figure/; pdflatex foo.tikz` in the terminal, and see what `pdflatex` says (you'd better remove `\nonstopmode` in `foo.tikz`)

Judging from the error log you posted, it seems there is something wrong in the LaTeX preamble in `foo.tikz`.

Comment: I had problems described, and when I completed step 3 described above, pdflatex installed a couple of extra packages (ms.tar.lzma and xcolour.tar.bz2) and then ran fine. I could then compile in RStudio without the errors!