# Memory issue when producing dense TikZ figure (14500 points scatterplot) with knitr

Tags: r, sweave, knitr

I have a series of plots in my document which are correctly drawn by knitr with `dev=tikz`. Yet figure number 7, which is much more dense than the others in terms of data points, `foo`, doesn't:

```
label: foo (with options) 
List of 3
 $ include   : logi TRUE
 $ fig.width : num 3
 $ fig.height: num 3

Quitting from lines 142-149 (myfile.Rnw) # These are chunk's first and list line
Error: failed to compile figure/foo.tikz to PDF

Execution halted
```

Deleting all accessory files, cache and figure directories and re-runing `knitr` doesn't solve the problem.

I followed the suggestions of [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/137493/27466):

`figure/foo.log` concluded with

```
[...other stuff...]
Package microtype Info: Loading generic settings for font family
(microtype)             `zplm' (encoding: OT1).
(microtype)             For optimal results, create family-specific settings.
(microtype)             See the microtype manual for details.
Package microtype Info: Loading generic settings for font family
(microtype)             `cmss' (encoding: OT1).
(microtype)             For optimal results, create family-specific settings.
(microtype)             See the microtype manual for details.
\c__siunitx_mathtt_int=\count441
Package microtype Info: Loading generic settings for font family
(microtype)             `cmtt' (encoding: OT1).
(microtype)             For optimal results, create family-specific settings.
(microtype)             See the microtype manual for details.

Runaway definition?
->
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=5000000].
\pgf@sys@bp ...rrentprotocol {\the \pgfutil@toks@ 
                                                  }}
l.13807 ...=0.30] ( 49.08, 79.20) circle (  2.13);

If you really absolutely need more capacity,
you can ask a wizard to enlarge me.


Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 57490 strings out of 493734
 1253899 string characters out of 6146348
 5000001 words of memory out of 5000000
 60062 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 16802 words of font info for 45 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1328 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 59i,3n,92p,10362b,776s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
No pages of output.
```

I couldn't spot anything wrong in `figure/foo.tikz`

After running `xelatex foo.tikz` I got a similar conclusion

```
[...other stuff...]

Runaway definition?
->
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=5000000].
\pgf@sys@bp ...rrentprotocol {\the \pgfutil@toks@ 
                                                  }}
l.13807 ...=0.30] ( 49.08, 79.20) circle (  2.13);

No pages of output.
```

The problem seems about memory (isn't it?). So how could I fix it?

**EDIT:**

I was able to replicate the error with a MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{article}

\begin{document}

<<opt, include=FALSE, cache=TRUE, cache.lazy=FALSE>>=
library(ggplot2)

# Global options
options(tikzDefaultEngine='xetex')
opts_chunk$set(echo=FALSE, results=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, include=FALSE, 
               cache=TRUE, cache.lazy=FALSE,
               dev='tikz', out.width='.90\\linewidth', fig.show='asis')
theme_set(theme_classic())
@

<<foo, include=TRUE, fig.width=3, fig.height=3>>=

set.seed(99)
data <- data.frame(vector1 = as.integer(rlnorm(14500, sdlog = 2)),
                   vector2 = as.integer(rnorm(14500)))

ggplot(data, aes(vector1, vector2)) + geom_point(alpha=.2)
@


\end{document}
```

By reducing the length of `vector1` and `vector2` to 14 I get my plot, then it is clearly a memory problem and specifically a problem generate by `dev=tikz` because I can produce a plot with the same 14500 length vectors without using the TikZ device.

Comment: There is probably an error in your figure, e.g. missing `;`, but we cannot verify it withot your MWE.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke I would exclude that: the figure loads with no problems in R.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case, you are basically out of luck. You cannot draw plots with too many graphical elements using the `tikz` device in R. You have to either simplify your plot, or use another graphical device (such as the default `pdf` device; if you really care a lot about the font family, you may take a look at [this blog post](http://yihui.name/en/2010/03/font-families-for-the-r-pdf-device/)).