# XeLaTeX + knitr + Arial = error

Tags: xetex, knitr

When I compile the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}

\begin{document}

Hello.

<<foo, dev='tikz'>>=
library(ggplot2)
qplot(1)
@

\end{document}
```

I get the error

```
Line 10: Error in getMetricsFromLatex(TeXMetrics, verbose = verbose) :
```

I get no error when I omit

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}
```

or `dev='tikz'`. Looking at Yihui's answer here ([How to debug if Knitr quits unexpectedly when composing tikz figure](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/137231/how-to-debug-if-knitr-quits-unexpectedly-when-composing-tikz-figure)), I followed his debugging steps.

> 1. check the log file figure/foo.log for the error message

There is no file `figure/foo.log`

> 2. open figure/foo.tikz (it is supposed to be a complete LaTeX document), and see if you can spot anything wrong

Nothing appears wrong in the preamble, but there is only a blank line between `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`.

> 3. try cd figure/; pdflatex foo.tikz in the terminal, and see what
>      pdflatex **[edit: xelatex]** says (you'd better remove \nonstopmode in foo.tikz)

Unsurprisingly, `xelatex foo.tikz` runs fine, but produces no output.

Comment: Have you tried to open your document on external pdf  file? Maybe it's just the console that doesn't make appear your work

Comment: No pdf file is produced.

Comment: this seems to be a known issue https://github.com/yihui/tikzDevice/issues/46